# wxwidget with MinGW [compiliing/linking to wxmsw26ud_core ]

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, mingw, wxwidgets

Using:

```
Compiler: 4.81 GCC (MINGW)
OS: windows 7
wxwidgets: version (2.8) & (2.6) [out of frustration tried both versions]
installation instruction followed: wxwidget [wx/doc/install.txt]
```

Having problems installing `wxwidgets`; I have tried both the `MSYS` method and using the `cmd.exe` but cannot seem to get it working

So tried a fresh install recently and I get the following error:
`ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw26ud_core`

So since it is a linking error; I checked `C:\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib\` and the `wxmsw26ud_core` is missing. So I am guessing there is something wrong in the build process.

For reference, I am using the following `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0` under `C:\wxWidgets\build\msw`

Any suggestion what would make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, wxWidgets 2.6 is an incredibly old version, you won't find any support for it any longer. This being said, even it should have been built and 2.8 definitely should as well. But clearly it didn't, so you must have got an error after running make. Unfortunately you don't tell us what this error was, so I don't know how to help you.

My own recommendation is to get wxWidgets 2.9.5 and use [configure and make under Cygwin](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2011/06/choosing-gcc-for-building-wxwidgets.html) but using `mingw32-make` should work too.

Comment: Sorry I did not note the error during the build process; Will try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: **Problem Solved:** It was related to the newer 'MinGW compilers' and **MAYBE** the default `setup.h` file (also i disabled `UNICODE`). So I ended up using `MinGW 4.6.2 (2011)` with 'wxwidgets 2.8' **So it works now**

Comment: Sorry as I had compiled wx  uncountable times before posting the problem over here, I did not try to build it again. Again sorry about that.